# Python - Write to file with color and font

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to write to a file using grey text and Liberation Sans font.

This works in the terminal:

```
print '\033[1;30m' + sentences2[i] + '\033[1;m'
```

This doesn't work when I try to write to a file:

```
f.write('\033[1;30m' + sentences2[i] + '\033[1;m')
```

Output:

When you’re working with pixels, sometimes it’s useful to get the x- and/or y-values for a pixel you’re working with.#[1;30mWhen you’re working with pixels, sometimes it’s useful to get the x- and/or y-values for a pixel you’re working with.#[1;m

Also, how do I make it a certain font?

Comment: You cannot write to a plain-text file in anything other than plain text. The color thing is only a convention of terminals to use a different color, when they appear. To do what you want, you need to use another target file format, like HTML or RTF.

Comment: Cool, you saved me hours of work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to my comment: If you want to create an HTML file (where you can apply formatting), try this: Name the file `index.html` (or anything ending with `.html`), and write to it:

```
f.write("""
  <p style="color: red; font-family: 'Liberation Sans',sans-serif">
    {}
  </p>
""".format(sentences2[i]))
```

*Edit:* I should mention, that the ANSI control codes that you found (like `\033[1;30m`) *can* be made useful again. `less` provides a command-line switch `-R` (for “raw” output), that will make your terminal interpret them.

```
less -R my_file.txt
```

However, you need your users to somehow do this on their own.

Comment: Thanks.  But now I am getting funny symbols at the beginning of the text.  I am using Firefox with Ubuntu.  Sample output:  ï»¿Whether you're new to....

Comment: In addition to that, there is a problem writing the special characters from other languages, such as this Portuguese word: nÃ³s.  It should be: nós

Comment: @Tony that is another question for another time.

Comment: @Tony with HTML I set you on a slippery slope directly heading into web development :). For intros on HTML, see e.g. http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web or http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/.

Comment: @Boldewyn - Is there a different type of file that I can write to using Python and still get this type of font formatting?